# How to fix 'Background Image in ListView' in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I tried to create different backgrounds with images for each listView element. My problem is how to fill this place (except icon at the beginning)  with a full picture and not move any of my current elements in it.

Layout Without bg - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGaoq.jpg

I've tried to use to Relative Layout and Grid Layout with 'aspects' and etc., but results are below:

My try - https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DwS7.jpg

```
<ListView x:Name="deckListView"
          RowHeight="50"
          ItemSelected="DeckListView_ItemSelected"
          Margin="5, 0, 10, 0">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>

            <ViewCell>

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Image >
                        <Image.Source>
                            <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding ImageSource}"
                                CachingEnabled="True"
                                 CacheValidity="14"/>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>

                    <!-- BG IMG-->
                    <RelativeLayout >
                    <Image Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" > 
                        <Image.Source>
                                <UriImageSource Uri="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/wiedzmin/images/d/d7/G_SS_Kr%C3%B3l_Foltest.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20180317231055"/>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>

                        <!-- LIST VIEW ELEMENT-->
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <Label Text="{Binding NameDeck}"

                            FontSize="Medium"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Fraction}"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Win}"
                               TextColor="Green"
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               Style="{StaticResource bottomLabel}"/>

                            <Label Text=":" 
                               Style="{StaticResource bottomLabel}"
                               FontSize="Small"
                               Margin="0,0,0,5"/>

                            <Label Text="{Binding Lose}"
                               TextColor="Red"
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               Style="{StaticResource bottomLabel}"/>

                            <Label x:Name="winRatio"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                               Text="{Binding WinRatio, StringFormat='{0}%'}"
                               FontSize="Large"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I'm so sorry If I forgot about something to paste.

Comment: this is how i usually do the styling on my Lists: have a parent StackLayout to fill all the available space (vertical and horizontal options set to FillAndExpand), then inside have a grid with collum and row definitions (from  the images you provided, it would be something like 2 rows and 4 collums), and then, use the Grid.RowSpan and Grid.CollumSpan depending where i want an image to fill, i can provide you with examples if you still have some problems getting it right, here is the documentation for the grid: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid

Comment: I guess you need to handle this problem yourself. The question doesn't go much beyond 'write the code for me'. If you have some specific problem with layout it is fine, but if you don't understand layout at all which seems to be the case, you need to go back and learn it.

Comment: You have to learn how different layouts work in Xamarin.forms. Please read document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/). Under each layout, there is an [Exploring a Complex Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/) example for you to better understand how it works. If you want to use stacklayout, the first step you should do is to remove the RelativeLayout  tags in your code so that the image will stay at the begin position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check Jason's answer in the [Xamarin Forums discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17794/image-as-background) that does the same thing.

He shows how you can use a basic AbsoluteLayout to do the same...

```
var myLayoutWithAllMyNormalStuff = <make it>;
var backgroundImage = new Image { ... };

ContentPage page = new ContentPage {
Content = new AbsoluteLayout {
 Children = {
  {backgroundImage, new Rectangle (0, 0, 1, 1), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All},
  {myLayoutWithAllMyNormalStuff, new Rectangle (0, 0, 1, 1), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All}
  }
 }
};
```